# Can an email address attached to key be traced back to me?

Tags: email, pgp, protonmail

I used my actual protonmail email address at the start of creating my own key. Can this email address be traced to me?

So when I sign something with my key and it's decrypted, can anyone see the email address attached to it that I used to first create key?

Comment: I think you have some misunderstandings. When you sign the message, it's not encrypted, so it isn't "decrypted". For someone to verify the signature, they need your public key. So, like I was suggesting, your question is "is my email embedded in the public key?", and that's an easy thing to look up (it is).